# SublimeHaskell doesn't use path

Tags: haskell, sublimetext3, hsdev

Using Windows 10. Compiling and Executing Prelude functions / basic Haskell Code with ctrl+b works.

Error on starting:

```
SublimeHaskell: hsdev executable couldn't be found!
It's used in most features of SublimeHaskell
Check if it's installed and in PATH
If it's not installed, run 'cabal install hsdev' to install hsdev
You may also want to adjust 'add_to_PATH' setting
```

My SublimeHaskell User settings:

```
{
"add_to_PATH":
[
    "C:/Users/Arne/AppData/Roaming/cabal/bin",
],
"enable_hdevtools": true
}
```

hdevtools.exe is in the right folder.

Importing packages I installed via cabal install don't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Windows uses backslashes, have you tried using them? Only thing to keep in mind is escaping them.

Example:

```
"C:\\Users\\Arne\\AppData\\Roaming\\cabal\\bin"
```